# Не получается добавить элементы одного ArrayList в другой

Tags: java, android

Массив arr=asd, asd, asd, ;, fgf

```
ArrayList Que=new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

razdelN=0;
razdelK=Element(arr,2);

for (i=razdelN;i<=razdelK;i++){
     Que.add(arrayList.get(i));
}

private int Element(String[] arr,int i){

    for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j].equals(" ;")) {
            ch=j+1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ch;
}
```

Приложение вылетает из-за `Que.add(arrayList.get(i));`

Comment: размер `arrayList` равен пяти? Может цикл с нуля начинать: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { ...`

Comment: Покажите инициализацию переменных, заполнение `arrayList` и саму ошибку

Comment: еще смущает `Que` с большой буквы :)

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=5 && i < arrayList.size(); i++)` - это позволит избежать наиболее вероятной ошибки

Comment: @lDrakonl arrayList берёт значения из массива arr `ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));`
`ArrayList Que=new ArrayList();`

Comment: вы дополните вопрос всем необходимым для воспроизведения проблемы. И ошибкой. Мы сейчас занимаемся гаданием по фотографии

Comment: @lDrakonl Дополнил

Comment: выложите стек ошибки

Comment: @Виктор [это?](https://pp.userapi.com/c834203/v834203004/364fc/M-cr03J7BvI.jpg)

Comment: Добавьте стек ошибки текстом к вопросы, смотреть на картиночки из комментариев немножко сложно. И опишите задачу которую вы решаете более полно, потому что вы творите что-то странное

Comment: И что такое `ch` и что за магия вообще с ним твориться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример кода, который находит в строке точку с запятой и копирует так как делали вы данные из одного `ArrayList` в другой `ArrayList` до точки с запятой.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created on 25.11.2017.
 */
public class Main {
    static ArrayList<String> que = new ArrayList(); //имена переменныз в Java принято начинать с маленькой буквы, по этому Que -> que
    static String[] arr =  {"asd","asd","asd"," ;","fgf"};
    static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ch = getElementPosition(arr, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ch; i++) {
            que.add(arrayList.get(i));
        }

        // вывод результата:
        for(String str : que) { //Проход по всему ArrayList и вывод
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }


    public static int getElementPosition(String[] inputString, int startPosition){
        if(startPosition > inputString.length || startPosition < 0){
            return -1; // стартовая позиция вне диапазона массива. Поиск ничего не нашел
        }
        for (int i = startPosition; i < inputString.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].equals(" ;")) {
                return  i;
            }
        }
        return -1; // если поиск не увенчался успехом
    }
}
```

Справедливости ради следует заметить, что данную задачу можно решить намного проще

Comment: //массивы нумируются с 0, по этому ищем до "длинна массива" -1. Поэтому и надо идти до i < inputString.length. Ваш код игнорирует последний элемент

Comment: справедливо. исправил